# php 7.1 and SCA_SDO - where find package (ubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: php, package, ubuntu-server

I need to generate XML on the base XSD file. PHP documetation recommended SCA_SDO.
Try install SCA_SDO

```
 sudo pecl install SCA_SDO
```

And i'm have this error:

```
pear/SCA_SDO requires PHP (version >= 5.1.0, version <= 6.0.0), installed version is 7.1.2
No valid packages found
```

Where can I find the package SCA_SDO for version php 7?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm did this with function simplexml_load_string. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php